# Pandas - KeyError: ('var', 'occurred at index 1414') - looping with a for

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe with this columns

```
Gestor  No.Obligacion   Descripcion Codigo Gestion  Fecha Gestion   Fecha pago1 Fecha pago2 Fecha pago3 Fecha pago4 Fecha pago5 Fecha pago6 Fecha pago7 Fecha pago8 Fecha pago9
```

And i want to compare `Fecha pago1` with `Fecha pago2`

I have this for with a function

```
for x in range(1, 8):
    def cambiarrepetidos(row):
        if row['Fecha pago{0}'.format(x)] == row['Fecha pago{0}'.format(x+1)]:
            return "Sin Pago"
        else:
            pass
    RS2['Fecha pago1'] = RS.apply(cambiarrepetidos, axis=1)

input

FechaPago1  FechaPago2
12/09/2018   12/09/2018
11/09/2018   12/09/2018
09/09/2018   10/09/2018

output

FechaPago1   FechaPago2
12/09/2018   Sin Pago
11/09/2018   12/09/2018
09/09/2018   10/09/2018
```

I want to do the same with FechaPago1 FechaPago2 FechaPago3 to FechaPago9

But i run it and i get this

```
KeyError: ('Fecha pago1', 'occurred at index 1414')
```

Can you help me please?, sorry for my english

Comment: It would be better if you post a [mcve] and the expected output. Its difficult to understand what are you trying to do without a sample of your dataframe

Comment: ok, thanks, like that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are comparing the values in two columns and if they are same, replace the value in column 2 with 'Sin Pago'.

You can do that without a loop. The first statement in loc is the condition, and if the condition is true, assign a value to column specified after the condition.

```
df.loc[df['FechaPago1'] == df['FechaPago2'], 'FechaPago2'] = 'Sin Pago'

    FechaPago1  FechaPago2
0   12/09/2018  Sin Pago
1   11/09/2018  12/09/2018
2   09/09/2018  10/09/2018
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps me a lot! But do yo know why i was getting that KeyError?